# Two ways of finding families of curve orthogonal to circle

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, polar-coordinates, parametric, plane-curves

Given the family of curves $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, I wish to find another family of curves orthogonal to it. One method is as follows:
$$x^2+y^2=r^2 \implies 2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}.$$
Inverting the slope to find curves orthogonal to it, we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x} \implies y=cx,$$
as we expected. However, if we do not know the trick of writing $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and instead brute force via substitution $$x=r\cos\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{r}\right)\right) \implies \frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{y}{r\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{r^2}}}.$$
Inverting the differential gives
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{r\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{r^2}}}{y}\implies x=r\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{r^2}}-r\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{r^2}}\right)+c,$$
which does not recover the expected result. The first term is just $x$, so what is left is a constant $c$ equal to a function of $x$, which is not true. Can anyone see why writing $x$ in terms of $y$ directly won't lead to an orthogonal curve?

Hence I considered a simple case. Suppose $x=f(r), y=g(r)$ are some more complicated parametric curves. What we typically do is to perform implicit differentiation on the function $h(x,y,r)=0$ and then invert the slope to get a differential equation for the orthogonal curves. It seems like the brute force approach above is following this procedure, but somehow cannot lead to the correct answer.

Comment: I think that what you want to do is to find the tangent to the curve. Then the normal to the tangent gives the orthogonal curve. For example, if you have the curve $z(t)$ then the unit normal vector $u=i\frac{\dot z}{|\dot z|}$. The equivalent Cartesian equations can be found in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve).